# String = String comparison style (theory?)

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, vba

I can't test the code out at the moment (no laptop), but in a `If` statement as below:

```
Dim StrA As String, StrB As String

IF StrA = StrB Then
   'code for true result
Else
   'code for false result
End If
```

Does the `If`statement check the strings in a binary or textual manner?

Comment: What do you mean binary or textual?  My inclination is to say the question is irrelevant.  It checks the strings for equality and that's all that's needed to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comparison is usually textual, stra=STRA, but you can use StrComp:

```
 StrComp("stra","STRA",vbbinarycompare)
```

http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/strcomp-function-HA001228914.aspx

```
Sub IsIt()
'Option Compare Database (default): True
'Option Compare Text : True
'Option Compare Binary : False
If "stra" = "STRA" Then
    Debug.Print True
Else
    Debug.Print False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this builds with Beth's answer but gives me something to test it out as well!

Answer (score 2):

depends on [settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t3khw5f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)  `option compare text` is most common, I think